# Not work cron the task

Tags: php, cron, centos

Not work cron the task.

```
crontab -l

1 0 * * * php /home/bitrix/ext_www/art-code.su/cron/script.php
```

path `php /home/bitrix/ext_www/art-code.su/cron/script.php` - Work script. Return - `1`

Why does not it work?

script code:

```
echo mail("example@mail.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3".time()." end");
```

OS - centos6

Cron - work

`[bitrix@localhost ~]$ systemctl status crond.service -l`

`crond.service - Command Scheduler
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-10-11 16:19:51 EET; 1min 34s ago
Main PID: 543 (crond)
CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
└─543 /usr/sbin/crond -n`

`Oct 11 16:19:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
Oct 11 16:19:51 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Command Scheduler...
Oct 11 16:19:52 localhost.localdomain crond[543]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 45% if used.)
Oct 11 16:19:52 localhost.localdomain crond[543]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)`

Answer (score 0):

To execute your *php script* on a **crontab**, you should tell the cron **where is** the *php executable*.

So, in case your php executable where in `/usr/local/bin/php`, your crontab line should be something like this:

```
1 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/bitrix/ext_www/art-code.su/cron/script.php
```

Comment: Did you check your php executable dir? Or did you use mine without check it?

Comment: I checked. I have php in /usr/bin/php

/usr/bin/php /home/bitrix/ext_www/art-code.su/cron/script.php - work in the console